# Sitecore SXA All Facet values not reflecting

Tags: sxa, solr, search-facet

I am using `Sitecore 10.1 SXA` with `Solr` on `Azure Kubernetes`. On a *Multicheck list filter*, the facet values coming from `sitecore_sxa_web_index` *exceed 100* values, hence `facet.limit` increased to *1000*. Usually, all the facet value starts showing up once the facet limit is expanded, but this time only specific to `sitecore_sxa_Web_index` the facet values **do not appear**, whereas, for *other custom index*, facet values of *more than 100 appear*.

I have checked the Solr logs and search logs, but could not see any error.

Would appreciate any kind of help or suggestions.
Thanks in advance